# How do I find all commits without auditors?

Tags: audit, phabricator

I have set up a Herald rule that automatically assigns an auditor depending on the branch name.

I noticed some commits get through even though they should be found by this Herald (it's less than 1% that falls through)

Is there a way to find these commits? I can't seem to query on any of the audit statuses or properties, nor can I find these commits in the Audit module (they don't have the audit properties at all).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can query for this by going to `Diffusion` **>** `Browse Commits` **>** `Advanced Search` and searching for the "No Audits" Audit Status. [Here](https://secure.phabricator.com/diffusion/commit/query/advanced/) is the search form in the upstream phabricator.